# XDG_RUNTIME_ERROR not set in the environment

Tags: linux, user-interface, xserver

I found a useful and detailed answer at [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/928979). But it looks not work for me.

The full output of my program is:

```sh
peter@Peterlits:~/proj/skogkatt-new/server
 $ ./target/debug/server
Running...
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
WARNING: lavapipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only.
vulkan: No DRI3 support detected - required for presentation
Note: you can probably enable DRI3 in your Xorg config
thread 'main' panicked at 'Error in Device::create_swap_chain: surface does not support the adapter's queue family', /home/peter/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-0.7.1/src/backend/direct.rs:129:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
[1]    1205 segmentation fault  ./target/debug/server
```

The *answer* I said at begining tells me that I should change the `xauth` but even the user `root` raises the same error! It also tells me that I should use `xhost` to set the right of access X server. It looks great because losing the right of access X server means cannot use X server. But I can run other graphical application:

```sh
peter@Peterlits:~/proj/skogkatt-new/server
 $ firefox
# it works well...
```

Could you please tell what is the matter of the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`? By the way, I works on WSL2(M$ says that it has the full Linux kernel), and it uses `$DISPLAY`(`= <My Windows IP>:8500`) to communicate with VcXsrv, which can run X application on Windows(Sorry but the WSL2 need this way to access graphical application).

Comment: Anyone can install Linux on a PC and login as root.  So root coming over a network to an X server is no more trusted than any other user.

Comment: I think the VcXsrv just display can do not check if it is root or not... I cannot understand why I can open firefox but not the program that I writed.